# R; Using manipulate function and get : Error in (function (x) : unused argument (envir = <environment>)

Tags: r, environment

I intend to use `manipulate`:

```
    install.packages("UsingR")
    library(manipulate)
    library(UsingR)

    data(galton)

    ########## Manipulable Histogram ##########

    myHist <- function(mu, Color){
    hist(galton$child, col=Color, breaks=10)
    lines(c(mu,mu), c(0, 150), col="red", lwd=5)
    }

    manipulate(myHist(mu, Color), mu = slider(62, 74, step=.5),
    Color=picker("blue", "red", initial="blue"))
```

I always get this error while using manipulate:

> Error in (function (x)  : unused argument (envir = )

I do not see any issue in the code above. I have NO IDEA of why I get this error. My R session is clean and new.

I am using `R3.2 64 bits` through `R Studio Version 0.99.441`.
Any idea of the missing settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, by setting the "R" directory in Rstudio as my default working directory where the folder win-library is located.